# How to get length of largest alterate slices in a array?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting

```
array = [-9,-1,2,0,5,-6,7,-8,0,-1]
```

here in array i need to find the length of largest alternating slice (- to + or + to -) 
0 is either +ve or -ve

so for the above array the answer is 8 , because slice(1,7) length is largest alternate slice

space complexity:O(1)
time complexity:O(N)

Comment: you have not any 1 in your list?

Comment: @Kasra I think he means the slice from 1-7 (even though that does not seem right since 0 can be either positive or negative) -> `[-1, 2, 0, 5, -6, 7, -8, 0, -1]`. Wouldn't the answer be 9 with that splice?

Comment: @MikeKobit yes your are correct

Comment: @MikeKobit why not from -9?

Comment: Must they be *strictly* non-negative and non-positive, or would "-1, 3, 2, 4, 0" give a run of 5?

Comment: @Kasra because it should be alternative like +ve,-ve,0,+ve.....

Comment: i mean (-9 to 0) ? as 0 could be + or -

Comment: strictly alternative

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP published the question as: "please do my HW for me" and showed no effort in solving it by himself.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick way to visualize what's going on

```
data = [-9, -1, 2, 0, 5, -6, 7, -8, 0, -1]

is_pos = [n >= 0 for n in data]                 # [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
is_neg = [n <= 0 for n in data]                 # [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]

from itertools import cycle
alt = cycle([0, 1])
alt_pos = [n ^ a for n,a in zip(is_pos, alt)]   # [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
alt_neg = [n ^ a for n,a in zip(is_neg, alt)]   # [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

# you are looking for the longest run of 0s or 1s
```

For an O(1) space, O(n) time algorithm:

- O(n) time suggests you should scan through the list, considering one item at a time
- O(1) space suggests a constant number of state variables

so your algorithm will look something like

```
# state variables
pos_run_len     =  0
neg_run_len     =  0
longest_run_len =  0

for n in data:
    # update variables based on value of n

# when finished, longest_run_len == 8
```

Comment: can you please explain what alt_pos and alt_neg are assigned with ?

Comment: and this is giving the wrong answer as 0 can be positive and negative both.